# Bootstrap $(...).modal is not a function после .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Использую модальные окна от бутстрапа, сначала подключаю `jquery` потом `bootstrap`. Модальные окна работают нормально. Но когда подгружаю аяксом контент методом

```
$('#pageContainer').load(url);
```

В консоли выскакивает ошибка `$(...).modal is not a function` и соответственно модалки не работают. Если подключить бутстрап в том контенте который подгружается аяксом - все нормально. Но подключать скрипт в каждом подгружаемом контенте не вариант. Можно как-то решить проблему?

Comment: Проверьте не подключается ли jQuery дважды.
Попробуйте вызвать функцию `jQuery.noConflict();` перед `$('#pageContainer').load(url);`

Comment: кажется не подключается два раза, еще поищу. Если прописать jQuery.noConflict(); в консоли ошибка Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: добавь пример разметки куда загружаешь, и что загружаешь

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк на что повешены модальные окна? если на контент внутри контейнера `#pageContainer` то не удивительно, что не работает после обновления аяксом. Ведь, инициализация модальных окон происходит на существующие текстовые блоки. Смотрите в сторону делегирования. К примеру, ставте `click` на внешний контейнер и вызывайте модальные окна по клику.   

P.S. сделайте пож. песочницу, где модальные окна работают без обновления аяксом.